# numpy.ndarray valuse cannot be compared with if statement

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, numpy-ndarray, object-detection-api

I,m currently working on a tensorflow image processing project. Three types of objects are identified which is labled 1(car),2(bus) and 3(van) represented by 's_class'. The detected output object/objetcs is given by s_class, which is a numpy.ndarray. When i print the detected object number,

```
(boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
    [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
    feed_dict={image_tensor: frame_expanded})
s_class = classes[scores > 0.6]
print(s_class)
```

it gives an output like,

```
>>[2.]    #bus is detected
  [3. 2. 1.]    #all three objects(van,bus,car) are detected
  [1. 2. 3.]    
  [1. 2. 3.]
  [1. 2. 3.]
  [2. 1. 3.]
  [2. 1. 3.]
  [2. 1. 3.]
  [2. 1. 3.]
  [2. 3. 1.]
  [2. 3. 1.]
  []              #nothing is detected
  [2.]            #only second object is detected
  []
  [1.]            #only first object is detected
```

and continues...
The objects are not represented in the array in organized order(eg:- [1. 2. 3.] or [2. 1. 3.]...etc - it changes the position ) 
I need to print "ok" if object 1 is detected and print "notok" when object 2 and/or 3 is detected. Also object 1 is detected with object 2 and/or 3 it should print "notok". 
I tried,

```
if (s_class==1):
    print("ok")
elif (s_class==2 or s_class==3):
    print("notok")
elif (s_class==1 and (s_class==2 or s_class==3)):
    print("notok")
elif (s_class==1 and s_class==2 and s_class==3 ):
    print("notok")
```

This doesn't work. How can i compare this numpy.ndarray with above conditions?

Comment: What exactly is `s_class`?  Looks like an object dtype 1d array. And the elements are themselves arrays (?).  Or are they lists?  What kind of output do you expect?  Clearly the whole `s_class` is not equal 1.  So elements are equal to `[1.]`.  Others have a 1 among the 3 values.  What does it mean to say `s_class` is ok?  Your problem is not clear.

Comment: Write a function that takes on item from your array, turns it into a list (e.g. `item.tolist()`) and does the required testing on that list - length, any 1's, 2's etc; you choice.  Then just iterate through your array, passing each item to this function.  In other words, test it as you would a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare using `in`.

```
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], np.int32)
x0 = x[0] #array([1, 2, 3])

#True
1 in x0 and 2 in x0

#True
1 in x0 or 2 in x0

#False
1 in x0 and 4 in x0
```